# Balls in bin. Adding similar coloured ball at every turn.

Tags: probability

The bin has 3 black balls and one white ball. In one turn, a ball is picked at random and returned to the bin with another of the same colour. After 60 such turns, what is the probability that the ratio of black to white balls in the bin is the same as it was initially(3 to 1).

Comment: Isn't this just the Beta-Binomial or Polya Urn model?

Answer (score 3):

Let us look first at the probability of any *particular* sequence of picks that leads to $48$ black and $16$ white.

At stage $k$, where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $60$, we are choosing from $4+k-1$ balls. So the denominators in our probabilities range from $4$ to $63$.

The numerators that yield the $45$ additional blacks range from $3$ to $47$, and the numerators that yield the $15$ additional whites range from $1$ to $15$. Thus the probability of any particular sequence that yields the desired result is
$$\frac{[(3)(4)\cdots(47)][(1)(2)\cdot(15)]}{(4)(5)\cdots(63)}.\tag{1}$$
The $15$ additional whites can occur in any of $\binom{60}{15}$ places, so for our probability we multiply (1) by $\binom{60}{15}$. There is very considerable simplification.